# Run two commands for .bat to output text

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to run two commands to get a windows username and network drives list and export them to a text file. I can export the network shares with "net use > mapped_drives.txt" but then I try to combine that with "net user" to get the username also to save to the same text file it does not work. I've probably got the syntax group but any help would be appreciated.

I have tried "net user && net use > test.txt" to which I only get the results from net use command.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: use ">>" to append. Is that what you needed to know?

Comment: what you should do is `net user >test.txt`  next line `net use >>test.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i tried using adding >> to append however I believe I have the syntax wrong.

Comment: Thank you Tilman Hausherr having it on a new line created a required.

Comment: Although I think it is trivial, I've created an answer, maybe my comment wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your .BAT file so that it looks like this:

```
net user >test.txt
net use >>test.txt
```

The second line will append to the output file.